# Closed form for the finite sum $\sum_{h=1}^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \tan\frac{h\pi n}{k}$

Tags: closed-form, trigonometric-series

Consider the series $$\sum_{h=1}^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \sum_{n=0} ^\infty\frac1{2n+1}\tan\left(\frac{(2n+1)h}{k}\pi\right)$$ where $k$ is an odd prime. Is it always positive?

Moreover, is there a closed expression for the finite sum $\sum_{h=1}^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \tan\frac{h\pi n}{k}$ for $k$ an odd prime?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a glosed form for
$$f(k)=\sum_{h=1}^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\tan \left(\frac{\pi  h n}{k}\right)$$ but it is in terms of  the [q-digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).

For brevity, let $x=e^{\frac{2 i \pi  n}{k}}$
$$f(k)=\frac{i}{2}  (k-1)+$$ $$\frac {2i}{\log(x)}\left(\psi _x^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{i \pi }{\log (x)}\right)-\psi
   _x^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(k-\frac{2 i \pi }{\log
   (x)}+1\right)\right)\right)$$

The fact that $k$ is an odd prime numbers does not make the problem different.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why the sum has the form you wrote please?

Comment: @Flyingpencil. Just because there is no other way to do it (at least, as far as I know).

Comment: Is there an expression for the tan series from 1 to infinity? And the expression you wrote is by subtraction? Where can I find such an expression?

Comment: @Flyingpencil.  Ping me tomorro (dinner Time hère). Cheers